# How to format the template to share images on facebook wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to share on Facebook wall some content from my website my script looks something like this .

```
<input data-mini="true" name="Compartir" type="button" id="Compartir" 
    value="1" onClick="connect('http://www.yoz.com','Adds being posted','This add contans something ')" >   

<script>
function connect($link, heading, description) {

    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: heading,
        link: $link,
        caption: 'hey I just posted an add',
        description: description,
        message: 'Hello'
    });
}
</script>
```

My question is how I can add an image to this share function . So that users can see an image in the add that has been posted on facebook wall along with the other description

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the picture attribute to the post 
FB.ui({ method: 'feed', name: heading, link: $link, caption: 'hey I just posted an add', description: description, message: 'Hello', picture:"link of the picture" });